# Unable to access Variable value using nodejs exports?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hey i have fallen into a situation where i cannot access a variable which i have set within a nodejs module which i have exposed with module exports to access from the main file, i will show you below:

**Login.js**:

```
let DEVICES;
function a() {
  return DEVICES;
}

async function init() {
  try {
    const __devices = await _db_get_devices();
    DEVICES = new DeviceCollection(__devices);
    console.log(a()) <-- **Returns the object correctly**
  } finally {
    console.log("Login Initialised!");
  }
}

module.exports = { init, a }
```

Below is the code that is having issues:

**App.js**

```
const Login = require('./func/Login');

Login.init() <-- **runs init function no issues**

console.log(Login.a()); <-- **returns undefined**
```

I have figured that its something to do with async but that is why i setup a function to call it later so not sure if there is a better method to calling the variable when its set.

Comment: Wait for `init` to finish first: `await Login.init()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`init` is an async function, so following statement

```
console.log(Login.a())
```

will run before `init` function has executed completely. Hence you get undefined because `DEVICES` isn't initialized yet.

You can return `DEVICES` from the `init` function and call `init` function as shown below

```
Login.init()
  .then(data => console.log(data))    // log the return value of init function
  .catch(error => console.log(error);
```

or you could call function `a` after `init` function has executed completely

```
Login.init()
  .then(() => console.log(Login.a()))
  .catch(error => console.log(error);
```